# Read and store data from DynamoDB in variable in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to read out data from my DynamoDB Table. I don't just want to log the data to the console but rather use this data to perform another function. My code right now is looking like this:

```
  var params = {
    TableName: "eventsList",
    Limit: 100
  };

  docClient.scan(params, onScan);
  var count = 0;

  function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));

    } else {        
      console.log("Scan succeeded.");
      data.Items.forEach(function(itemdata) {
        console.log("Item :", ++count,JSON.stringify(itemdata));
        tester[itemdata.name] = itemdata.date;

      });
      // continue scanning if we have more items
      if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
        console.log("Scanning for more...");
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        docClient.scan(params, onScan);
      }
    }
    return tester;
  }
  console.log(tester);
```

The output I receive is the following:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942 Version: $LATEST
2020-02-12T11:29:30.961Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    GetEventToday handler called
2020-02-12T11:29:31.601Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    {}
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Scan succeeded.
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Item : 1 {"name":"firstTestEvent","date":"03/1/2020"}
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Item : 2 {"name":"anotherTestEvent","date":"04/3/2020"}
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Item : 3 {"name":"newtestevent","date":"04/4/2020"}
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Item : 4 {"name":"secondTestEvent","date":"02/9/2020"}
2020-02-12T11:29:31.821Z    d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942    INFO    Item : 5 {"name":"thirdTestEvent","date":"03/5/2020"}
END RequestId: d1e2770c-24ef-4ee6-8570-c5f8bb4ee942
```

So as shown the log of tester is empty (INFO { }). So this means tester is empty and I can't use the data I thought I stored in there. If I put the log inside the brackets before `return tester` it's working and logs the data I have stored.

**So what do i have to change that the stored data in tester is returned to outside off** `onScan`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the Lambda function returns a result (an empty tester object) before the scans have actually completed (hence `tester` is empty). This is because the code doesn't handle asynchronous JavaScript correctly.

Here's an example of how your Lambda function can repeatedly scan a table, accumulate all items, and finally return those accumulated results.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({'region': 'us-east-1'});

function tableScan(ExclusiveStartKey) {
  const params = {
    TableName: "eventsList",
    Limit: 100,
    ExclusiveStartKey,
  };

  return dc.scan(params).promise();
}

exports.handler = async (_event, _context) => {
  try {
    let itemCount = 0;
    let scanCount = 0;
    const results = [];
    let ExclusiveStartKey;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
    while (true) {
      const data = await tableScan(ExclusiveStartKey);
      console.log("Data:", data);
      ++scanCount;

      data.Items.forEach(item => {
        console.log("Item :", ++itemCount, JSON.stringify(item));
        results.push(item);
      });

      ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
      if (!ExclusiveStartKey) break;
    }

    console.log("Success:", results, scanCount, itemCount);
    return results;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this code, but still if I log results I receive an empty Array. And aswell the console.log in forEach is not logging anything to the console in this case.

Comment: Your symptoms suggest zero items returned by the scan. Is that possible? This code works fine for me with a simple DDB table in us-east-1. Have you logged the `data` response from `tableScan`? What does it show?

Comment: So if I add `console.log(tableScan())` after the last } I get the response that the Promise is pending `Promise  { <pending> }`

I'm doing it on eu-west-1 but this should no matter. (i changed this in your code to the for me needed 'eu')

Comment: Don't log the `tableScan()` call itself; it returns a promise. Log the fulfilled promise (i.e. `data`) after `const data = await tableScan(...)`.

Comment: I did this as well, put still no log. The thing is, even if it would log inside there and would get some output, it's still ot possible to access the things stored inside `data` from outside the scope. So if I want to call another function (i.e. to calculate the next event) after reading the data from the dynamoDB Table I could not use the data from `data` to perform this function..

Comment: You should probably just add console.log("About to do X") before each and every line of code so that you can verify that X is about to be executed. Log the results of each function call right afterwards. You'll quickly work out what is going wrong, I hope.

Comment: @Kroenik you should really spend a little time to understand this code. Run it as a Lambda under Node.js 12.x  just as written, but connect it to your region/table and update me with the logs (if it doesn't work).